# How to rotate UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I have a large UIScrollView canvas and I want completely rotate this scrollView. For this I try:

```
scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0)
```

but in this case I get:

[image]

it's not 90 deg. And in my opinion it rotate in 3D. How can I rotate it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation takes in radians, not degrees.

Try this:

```
import Darwin


scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0)
```